Creation of a new Query object instead of using the already exitsting one
Am learning about implementing DB transactions in golang and for that, the instructor was creating a query object which will be having access to all the CRUD methods. But he also have a object which is having the Query as a data member in the struct. Why cant we use that?
type Store struct {
    *Queries
    db *sql.DB // Required for creating transactions
}

// Method to generate a store object
func NewStore(db *sql.DB) *Store {
    return &Store{
        db:      db,
        Queries: New(db),
    }
}

// executeTx execute the function given to it
func (store *Store) executeTx(ctx context.Context, fn func(*Queries) error) error {
    // Initiate the transaction
    tx, err := store.db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // The New() is decalred for DBTX inteface and both sql.DB and sql.Tx satisfy them
    // This will return a query object which can be used for the execution of the function.
    // We can also use the query object of the store too but thats just for composition
    q := New(tx)
    err = fn(q)
    if err != nil {
        rbError := tx.Rollback()
        if rbError != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("tx err: %v, rollback err: %v", err, rbError)
        }
        return err
    }
    return tx.Commit()
}

Here, the Queries is already a struct which is declared as:
type DBTX interface {
    ExecContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
    PrepareContext(context.Context, string) (*sql.Stmt, error)
    QueryContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
    QueryRowContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) *sql.Row
}

func New(db DBTX) *Queries {
    return &Queries{db: db}
}

type Queries struct {
    db DBTX
}

func (q *Queries) WithTx(tx *sql.Tx) *Queries {
    return &Queries{
        db: tx,
    }
}

So my question is,
q := New(tx) err = fn(q)
being used but can we use it like this too?
err = fn(store.Queries)
I tried executing the code with the Query from the store struct and it works but will there be any difference between the two.

Based on the implementation of New, it  appears to be just fine to call fn(store.Queries)

Your Queries object is dependent on a DBTX interface:
type DBTX interface {
    ExecContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (sql.Result, error)
    PrepareContext(context.Context, string) (*sql.Stmt, error)
    QueryContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error)
    QueryRowContext(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) *sql.Row
}

type Queries struct {
    db DBTX
}

this is probably done for testing reasons, so Queries can only use these methods and you only have to mock them with some test db.
But the DBTX interface has no transaction functionality like BeginTx/Commit/Rollback, so Queries has no access to them and you have to use *sql.DB for that - that is kind of incomplete separation of concerns.
I can't say whether this is good design - maybe the Store should have some transaction interface too - it's hard to say without knowing the rest of the code. Maybe for learning purposes it's enough to show this technique once. Your instructor should actually be able to explain this.
With
    q := New(tx)
    err = fn(q.Queries)

you are using the transaction tx to execute the queries via fn(q), which you can roll back in an error case. Just
    q := store.Queries
    err = fn(q)

would only work when they are no errors, leaving you without the possibility to roll back an incomplete change in an error case. You could alternatively use:
    q := store.Queries.WithTx(tx)
    err = fn(q)

and I'm not sure why both are here.
